Flutter table_calendar show 2 months per page
I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar for my flutter web app, and I was wondering if we were able to customize it to show 2 months per page, because from what I see right now we can only show either 1 month, 2 weeks or 1 week. I checked the docs and available parameters and I just couldn't find something helpful
The expected result would have to be something like the image below 
I thought about making 2 calendar instances but it's just too messy, it would mess up animations and potentially be buggy in terms of functionalities and callbacks, so there must be an easier way.
Thank you for taking the time to read this
